# What size frame size will best fit me, 36" inseam

Tags: road-bike, frames

What size road bicycle frame is recommended for someone with a 36" inseam?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Kahlan. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking a question, [ask] would help you also. I think your question is likely to closed, probably as "too broad". It would help if you explained what research you've done, and why it didn't help you.

Comment: Evans cycles have a guide here: https://www.evanscycles.com/help/bike-sizing . But you'll need to sit on a few bikes to find the best fit.

Comment: I'm 6'8" just over the size of the chart. From the chart I can estimate a frame 64-67 cm would fit me. Is it simple as that or are there more qualifications for selecting a frame size?

Comment: If you 6'8" get a large frame, unless you like the feel of a smaller bike, but for road riding i would get an extra large or XXL if available in the model your looking at. I imagine you have a lot of legs (length not quantity :P) and even with a larger frame you will likely have your seat pretty high. I think it would be safe to shoot for as large a frame as you can find. Best bet however is to go to your LBS (local bike shop) and have them do a fit, or atleast get an idea of standover and reach.

Comment: Frame size is rather simple, once you get into an actual fit on said frame it gets a little more complicated as there are a lot of variables that come into play. Everyone's body is different so having a proper fit done will make sure your just where you need to be.

Comment: @Nate Yes, all the bikes I've seen cater for bipeds, either one, two, four, or more of them :-)